# Disabling MRTK solver components from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I'm currently trying to replicate the old "Tap to place" functionality from HoloToolKit and that's working ok. On a gameobject I have:

-Near Interaction Grabbable

-Manipulation Handler

-A script to apply/destroy the surface magnetism solver

-A script to change the layer of the game object.

The way it works right now is:

1) Spawn object with a button (Air tap)

2) Tap and hold to grab the object

3) In the manipulation handler events I have "On Manipulation Started" set to invoke the layer change script to move the object to the "Ignore raycast" layer, then apply the surface magnetism solver.

4) Move the object around to place on the ground/wall/table/etc.

5) Let go and the "On Manipulation Ended" event invokes the surface magnetism script to destroy the solver, then invokes the layer change script to set it back to default so it can be grabbed and moved again.

For the demo I'm making I also want to be able to rotate the object after placing it in the world, so I've been trying to use the Bounding Box utility set to just allow for rotation around the y axis. With this attached right now the above "kinda" works, but it's very jittery and sometimes ends up with the object not in the right place. I can't set the bounding box's layer to ignore raycast to replicate the above method, so I want to just disable it while manipulation is going on. This would also help with other aspects as destroying the solver seems to end up messing with the transform and after a few re-moves it stops recognizing test terrain in my scene. I think this is because the transforms get wonky but I'm not sure.

I tried writing a script using GameObject.GetComponent but it doesn't recognize the script. I even tried creating public fields so I can just drag the target component in but VS doesn't like that either.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ComponentOnOff : MonoBehaviour
{
public Component TargetComp;
public GameObject TargetObject;


// Start is called before the first frame update
public void ComponentOff()
    {
     TargetObject.GetComponent(TargetComp).enabled = false;

    }
}
```

This iteration has the error: Cannot convert from UnityEngine.Component to System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was built into the Manipulation handler.

In the events section you can just select the BoundingBox script and there is a "bool enabled" option.

No script needed.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused, but were you still looking for an answer, or is this an answer to your own question?

Comment: It's an answer to my own question. I realized it a few minutes after posting the original question.